# Determine the number of characters per line given a width (based on font-size, font-family)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way we can determine the number of characters per line for a given width of `div` based on parameters like `font-size`, `font-family`, etc?
Please give a cross browser solution or a head start regarding this.

Note: I have a text area whose width is variable so limiting the number of characters per line or solution involving columns and rows is not the solution I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're talking about a monospace* font, this answer isn't knowable without taking into consideration the specific text in question. As a basic example, note the difference between:

- `10 MONOSPACE X's` `XXXXXXXXXX`
- `10 MONOSPACE I's` `IIIIIIIIII`
- `10 VARIABLE X's_` XXXXXXXXXX
- `10 VARIABLE I's_` IIIIIIIIII

With a variable-width* font, the same number of characters, in the same font, may be two different widths. (hence the name)

**the term "monospace", "fixed-width", "fixed-pitch", or "non-proportional" font, is a font whose characters each take up the same amount of horizontal space. Conversely, "proportional", or "variable-width" fonts contain characters whose width may take up a varying amount of horizontal space.*

Comment: Good illustration, although "proportional" is a more commonly used term.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include a brief definition / list of alternate terms, for ease of future googling