# How to remove text that is overflown from element in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I am working on a web app, and this is my layout. The divs use

```
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
```

This visually is fine, and is also fine in a JSFiddle. But with the ability to make very long names has issues in the web app. This issue comes from the fact that it isn't technically removing the overflown text. It (as you would think with the word "hidden") hides it. How would you go about detecting overflown text in the ".Name" element and removing it? I would like to keep the same look and rules. Just the text that is hidden is removed.

LINK - https://jsfiddle.net/t29ffzan/12/

Comment: with CSS you cannot manipulate DOM and content, you  can only play with the visual

Comment: I know this. Should have hinted I was looking for a Jquery answer. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that not all letters take up the same amount of space as each other. For instance I and M where M (guessing) is ~ 3x as big as I. [See this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896119/determine-the-number-of-characters-per-line-given-a-width-based-on-font-size-f).

However, you can guess and get close but there's still no guarantee.

```
$('.Name').each(function() {

  let text = $(this).text();
  let width = $(this).parent('.Box').outerWidth();
  let fontSize = 18 - ( 18 * 0.35 ); // Hardcoded from CSS
  let count = width/fontSize;
  text = text.substr(0, count);  
  $(this).text(text);

});
```

This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t29ffzan/32/) is a working example of the above and uses the `font-size` in the CSS and removes ~ 35% to allow for more characters but depending on the actual letters uses the results may vary widely.

You **could** use a [fixed width font](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/fonts.en.html) as all the characters should take up the same amount of space. However, results still aren't going to be perfect.

Your best bet is the limit the character count when the name is created instead of having to go back and try and parse it after the fact.

Comment: So there really is no fool proof way other than straight up limiting character count? Because the issue with that is (say I made it 30) If you had 30 W's it would look fine. But as soon as you have 30 i's, the user may wonder why they can't use more room of the div.  Thanks.

Comment: I did a bit of digging myself and couldn't find any sure fire way. I also did a bit of testing with the fiddle you provided.

Comment: Kinda unbelievable. Really appreciate the help.

Comment: No problem but as with anything it's always good to do more research and find something that fits your individual scenario.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that comes to this post, `max-width: 40ch;` worked best for me.