# How to make the overflowed part of text completely removed by CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have some text in my div and want the overflowed text completely not be displayed by css. I know how to hide it by using `overflow: hidden;` in the following example, but in this situation the hidden text is still in the page (For example it is searchable). Actually I want the overflowed part of the text to be removed.

```css
div {
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px dotted black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Overflow</h2>
<div>You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The overflow property specifies what happens if content overflows an element's box. Searching "Overflow_Hide" word ctrl-F shows it is still present in the html page.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You cannot do this with CSS; it just hides text one way or another, it doesn't delete it. You would need to use JavaScript to detect which section of the phrase is truncated and remove it.

Comment: How it removes? Is it exactly possible to remove the overflowed text?

Comment: With JavaScript, yes it is possible to remove the overflowed text. Is using JavaScript an acceptable solution for you?

Comment: I should test it.

Comment: If using JS/jQuery, this could be a dupe target https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49820136/how-to-remove-text-that-is-overflown-from-element-in-jquery

Comment: if you do delete the overflowed text it won't be there if the user resizes (e.g. goes from portrait to landscape) Is that what is required?

Comment: Yes. It is what I actually need.